# Where is Chrome's "Merge tabs and apps" option on Android Tablet running Lollipop?

Tags: chrome-for-android, tablet, 5.0-lollipop

**System:**

- Nexus 9 32GB Wi-Fi
- Android 5.0.0 Lollipop LRX21R
- Chrome 39.0.2171.93

While researching this myself, most questions I found are about how to *disable* 'Merge tabs and apps,' but I haven't found one that fits my problem, I'm trying to *enable* it.

For example, [OMGChrome](http://www.omgchrome.com/disable-chrome-tabs-android-switcher/) explains how to *disable* this as follows:

- Open Google Chrome for Android
- Open the menu
- Select "Settings"
- Tap "Merge tabs and apps"
- Set the slider to off

Reversing these steps, for me, is unsuccessful. The "Merge tabs and apps" option does not exist for me, as far as I can tell.

[image: Chrome Settings]

This is a feature that I'd like to have, but don't know how to get.

Comment: You really did merge this quickly. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Merge tabs and apps" option *should be* inside the "Basics" header. However, as of current writing, it seems Google didn't add this feature for Android tablet. The same case was reported on [Android Central's forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-5-0-lollipop/464139-how-can-i-merge-tabs-apps-chrome.html), and the reply was

> It looks like that feature is only on Chrome on phones. It may be due to the fact that Chrome on tablets already has visible tabs, while Chrome on phones doesn't.

[image: Setting on phone]

<sub>Chrome 39.0 setting on Android phone</sub>

[image: Setting on tablet]

<sub>Chrome 39.0 setting on Android tablet</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That sounds like it would work, but when I navigate to the 'Basics' tab, I still don't see that option. Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/ejMhUSq

Comment: I didn't expect that... and I just found [this forum thread](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-5-0-lollipop/464139-how-can-i-merge-tabs-apps-chrome.html) regarding Chrome on Android tablet. I'm afraid it's impossible to have this feature on tablet...